# xslt deduplicate values by substring

Tags: xslt

I have following categories:

```
<categories>
    <category>anotherparent</category>
    <category>parent</category>
    <category>parent/child1</category>
    <category>parent/child1/subchild1</category>
    <category>parent/child2</category>
    <category>parent/child3/</category>
    <category>parent/child3/subchild3</category>
</categories>
```

Problem here is that the category path is "duplicated". Basically I'd like to remove all parent category paths and only include the most concrete level.
So the result should be something like this:

```
<categories>
    <category>anotherparent</category>
    <category>parent/child1/subchild1</category>
    <category>parent/child2</category>
    <category>parent/child3/subchild3</category>
</categories>
```

I can think about some java extension, but I can't find proper method/function how to do this in xslt and I'm pretty sure it should be easy.

It could be xslt 2 or 3.

Comment: There is a trailing `/` in `<category>parent/child3/</category>`. Is that a typo or can this be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(category)*">
    <xsl:param name="cats"/>
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$cats?2[$level]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$cats[?2[$level]]" group-by="?2[$level]">
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="$cats?1"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="categories">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(category ! [., tokenize(., '/')], 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

helps; assumes, like the comment asks, that a trailing `/` in `<category>parent/child3/</category>` is a typo and would be `<category>parent/child3</category>`. If `parent/child3/` can occur but should be treated as `parent/child3` then use `tokenize(., '/')[normalize-space()]` instead of `tokenize(., '/')`.

It might be cleaner to use a sequence of maps with two items in the function instead of a sequence of size 2 arrays:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(category)*">
    <xsl:param name="cats" as="map(xs:string, item()*)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$cats?tokens[$level]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$cats[?tokens[$level]]" group-by="?tokens[$level]">
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="$cats?cat"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="categories">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(category ! map { 'cat' : ., 'tokens' : tokenize(., '/') }, 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again, it might be necessary to use `tokenize(., '/')[normalize-space()]` instead of `tokenize(., '/')` if trailing or leading or in between slashes can occur but should be ignored.

Comment: yes the first works. The data I'm working with are really strange so sometimes there is a slash at the end sometimes it isn't there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you input XML is always in the format you posted, this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="category[starts-with(following-sibling::category[1],.)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxY

Comment: ah no, my data are slightly different and in your template if you change the order of categories then it won't work.